# NodeJs & Express Learning RESTFUL, when submitting form to update, it creates a new form with a new ._id instead of updating the original one

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, crud

I'm learning how to use an express server and RESTFUL routes. Currently I am unable to update my blog post, when I hit submit on my edit page it takes me to the original post that is not edited but when I go to the index page the original post is unchanged and there is a duplicate post with the edits I made with an new ._id. Im running this in a local environment. Database is Mongodb using Mongoose.

```js
//app.js file
const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  port = 3000;
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
////APP CONFIG
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/restful_blog', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false

});
////MONGOOSE/MODEL/CONFIG
const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  image: String,
  body: String,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
const Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);
////RESTFUL ROUTES
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/blogs');
});
//Index Route
app.get('/blogs', (req, res) => {
  Blog.find({}, (err, blogs) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render('index', {
        blogs: blogs
      });
    }
  });
});
//New Route
app.get('/blogs/new', (req, res) => {
  res.render('new');
});
//Create Route
app.post('/blogs', (req, res) => {
  //Create Blog
  Blog.create(req.body.blog, (err, newBlog) => {
    if (err) {
      res.render('new');
    } else {
      //Then, Redirect to Index
      res.redirect('/blogs');
    }
  });
});
//Show Route
app.get('/blogs/:id', (req, res) => {
  Blog.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundBlog) => {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect('/blogs');
    } else {
      res.render('show', {
        blog: foundBlog
      });
    }
  });
});
//Edit Route
app.get('/blogs/:id/edit', (req, res) => {
  Blog.findById(req.params.id, (err, foundBlog) => {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect('/blogs');
    } else {
      res.render('edit', {
        blog: foundBlog
      });
    }
  });
});
//Update Route
app.put('/blogs/:id', (req, res) => {
  Blog.findOneAndUpdate(req.body.id, req.body.blog, (err, updatedBlog) => {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect('/blogs');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/blogs/' + req.params.id);
    }
  });
});
////Starts Server
app.listen(port, () => console.log(
  `YelpCamp is running at http://localhost:${port}`
));
```

```js
//edit.js file
<%- include('partials/header') %>

<div class="ui main text container segment">
    <div class="ui huge header">
        Edit <%= blog.title %>
    </div>
    <form class='ui form' method="POST" action="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>?_method=PUT" >
        <div class="field">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input class="ui input" type="text" name="blog[title]" value="<%= blog.title %>">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Image</label>
            <input class="ui input" type="text" name="blog[image]" value='<%= blog.image %>'>
        </div><div class="field">
            <label>Blog Post</label>
            <textarea name="blog[body]"><%= blog.body %></textarea>
        </div>
          <input  class='ui basic button red big' type="submit">
    </form>
</div>


<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in the update route, you are using `findOneAndUpdate` and passed just the `id` to it, while you should pass an `object` to it as a filter

also, the `id` is in the `params` object not in the body, so we have to use `req.params.id` instead of `req.body.id`

so you have two options to solve this issue I guess

1- use `findOneAndUpdate`, but pass an object as a filter

```
//Update Route
app.put('/blogs/:id', (req, res) => {
  Blog.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body.blog, (err, updatedBlog) => {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect('/blogs');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/blogs/' + req.params.id);
    }
  });
});
```

2- or use `findByIdAndUpdate`, here you can pass the id directly

```
//Update Route
app.put('/blogs/:id', (req, res) => {
  Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.blog, (err, updatedBlog) => {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect('/blogs');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/blogs/' + req.params.id);
    }
  });
});
```

hope it helps

Comment: I tried both and  each one there was no changes to the blog post and no duplicate blog post as well.

Comment: are you sure no changes have been done to the post in database?, I mean may be the post has changed in db but you didn't retrieve that in the view, to retrieve the post after the update you have to add some options `{ new: true }` if you are using mongoose or { returnNewDocument: true } if you are using mongoDb

Comment: so the query will be something like that `Blog.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.id }, req.body.blog, { new: true }, (err, updatedBlog) => { .... } `

Comment: So I looked in the database and there is no changes, I added console.log(req.body.blog) to see if the updated information is there and it is. `//Update Route
app.put('/blogs/:id', (req, res) => {
    Blog.findOneAndUpdate({_id:req.body.id}, req.body.blog, {new: true}, (err, updatedBlog) => {
        if(err) {
            res.redirect('/blogs');
        } else {
            console.log(req.body.blog);
            res.redirect('/blogs/' + req.params.id);
        }
    });
});`

Comment: could you add the result of console.log here please, and also console.log the req.body.id to see if there is a problem with it, or it does not exist

Comment: `{
  title: 'Original Post -UPDATED',
  image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534361960057-19889db9621e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80',
  body: 'This is my original post, hopefully it changes!'
}` Original Post does not have the - UPDATED

Comment: and req.body.id too please?

Comment: hmmm, that's why nothing updated I guess, I think it should be req.params.id not req.body.id, could you give it a try?

Comment: great :), will update my answer too, to make it easier to anyone who needs some help :)